# Loading Static Content pdf2Html Itext 7

Tags: itext, itext7, converters, static-content, pdfhtml

Good afternoon.
I am trying to load static content for my Html to PDF converstion using Itext 7's PdfHTML add-on.
At this point I am just doing a hello world example following the boilerplate example on [their Website](https://git.itextsupport.com/users/bruno/repos/htmlsamples/browse/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/htmlsamples/chapter03/C03E02_Print.java):

My code doesn't deveate from that in significant anyway.  The only difference is that i am setting up a ConverterProperties object and adding that to the call.

```
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties()
                .setBaseUri("https://randomURIforReelzBro.com/");
        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream("src/htmldocs/randomHTMLforReelzBro.html"), new FileOutputStream(dest), converterProperties);
```

The content exists on my vpn and I can access it from the runtime of my IDE.
So if I put the full path of that URI in my browser I can clearly see the content (in this instance a JPEG).  The converted PDF is not seeing it however.  Am I missing something simple?  It is supposed to be a relative path according to the documentation on Itext's Website.  Should I only include the part of the path's that are common to all the Content Resources that my html page is using?  If you have any ideas let me know.  If I figure something out I will write up my answer for any one else struggling with this issue.

After doing a little bit of experimentation, it would appear as though the Jar has a very random response to locally hosted content.  I thought it might be a difference in https versus http but, I found examples of each that loaded and examples of others that didn't load.  All the content loads in a browser (obviously).  Also, setting the Base URI seems to have no effect whatsoever on the outcome?  I would say that is strange.  Any ideas anyone?  Particularly someone from the IText team?

Comment: Just ran wireshark and filtered only for GET requests 
http.request.method == "GET"
Doesn't look like it is even REQUESTING the other static content.  Trying to figure out why.

Comment: Please share your html file to reproduce the issue. Please also try to download static content into your local folder and see if it works or not when you specify your base uri pointing to a local folder.

Comment: With remote connections a lot of variables are present. For instance, as Java native web client is used, it sends its own User-Agent HTTP headers, which might affect the response if the server differentiates between user agents.

Comment: Please also look for the logging output of iText. Most likely you will find some hints there, especially if a remote resource was not resolved

Answer (score 1):

After looking into this issue it turns out that because the images were in a background tag of a Table Data element, The htmlToPDF wasn't even finding the images.
Background images in  elements are deprecated so I think Itext 7 Doesn't do anything with them.
After migrating the Images to a Style tag in the header:

```
<style>
    .blueimage1 {background-image: url("https://randomstaticcontent.screwy/random.gif"); }
    .blueimage2 {background-image: url("https://randomstaticcontent.screwy/randomA1.gif"); }
</style>
```

iText 7 was able to find the Static content and create the PDF.
Moral of the story, Search your HTML for deprecated tags before running through IText.